# Sentry source-maps - Troubleshooting

Tags: webpack, source-maps, sentry

I'm trying to get source maps working with Sentry for a reactjs application. I'm using webpack in conjunction with the SentryWebpackPlugin. The relevant configurations in the webpack config look like this:

```js
const SentryWebpackPlugin = require('@sentry/webpack-plugin');

const SentryOptions = {
  // sentry-cli configuration
  authToken: process.env.SENTRY_AUTH_TOKEN,
  project: process.env.SENTRY_PROJECT,

  // webpack specific configuration
  include: pathLibrary.resolve(__dirname, '..')
};

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'hidden-source-map',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[contenthash].js',
    publicPath: '',
    path: pathLibrary.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'public'),
    sourceMapFilename: '../tmp/sourcemaps/[file].map'
  }
}

if (DEPLOY_ENVS.includes(env)) {
  module.exports.plugins.push(new SentryWebpackPlugin(SentryOptions));
}
```

When I build and deploy the application, I can indeed see source maps and sources in Sentry, however, the code shown on the issues page does not appear readable. This leads me to believe that I have done something incorrectly with naming the output files or source maps.

[image: sentry artifacts table]

[image: sentry issue page]

Comment: Is Sentry your last running webpack plug-in? There’s a note in the docs that if it’s not, it might not send the final version of the source map. The note is right above [Advanced Usage](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/sourcemaps/tools/webpack/#advanced-usage)

Comment: @AdamMarshall yes, I'm pushing to the plugins array just before exporting the module. `module.exports.plugins.push(new SentryWebpackPlugin...)`

Comment: Have the same issue with vite and vue, using hidden source maps. I'm using sentry-cli which according to the documentation adds a header for sentry source-map mapping, but still don't see readable code in the issues.